# Is there a function in java that works like SUBSTRING function but for integers?

Tags: java

is there a function in java that works like SUBSTRING function but for integers.  Like for example the user's input is 456789, I want to break it into two part and put them into different variable. and divide them. for example,

user's input : 456789

the first 3 numbers will be in variable A.

the last 3 numbers will be in variable B.

pass = A/B;

can someone help me how can I do this,

thanks.

Comment: Why not convert the number to a `String`, split it, and convert the parts back?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341996/getting-part-of-a-number-string

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't think so. The OP is talking about taking the first three digits of a `Integer`, not a `String`. It can be easily done by converting it to string, but it's not a duplicate to me

Comment: @BackSlash that's what I meant.

Answer (score 12):

Use integer division and the modulus operator:

```
int input = 456789;
int a = input / 1000;
int b = input % 1000;
```

Comment: +1 - Good solution: using math instead of `Strings`.

Comment: @BackSlash - Ah, but ultimately Strings are math too.

Comment: Good solution, but not general enough incase he wants to use for numbers other than 3 and 3 (which would require changing the 1000). Also does not support getting a part of the int that is in the middle of the number like substring does.

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf to get part that is in the middle, chain them. `123456789 / 1000 = 123456, 123456 % 1000 = 456`, and you could use `Math.pow( 10, x )` for different "lengths". So this *method* would work for the scenarios you describe, albeit with some modifications.

Comment: This is just brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mathematical based implementation for positive and negative integers (probably can be optimized):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(substring(2, 0, 1)); // prints "2"
    System.out.println(substring(2523, 2, 2)); // prints "23"
    System.out.println(substring(-1000, 0, 2)); // prints "-1"
    System.out.println(substring(-1234, 0, 4)); // prints "-123"
    System.out.println(substring(-1010, 2, 1)); // prints "0"
    System.out.println(substring(-10034, 3, 2)); // prints "3"
    System.out.println(substring(-10034, 2, 4)); // prints "34"
}

public static int substring(int input, int startingPoint, int length) {
    if (startingPoint < 0 || length < 1 || startingPoint + length > size(input)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (input < 0 && startingPoint == 0 && length < 2) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("'-' can not be returned without a digit");
    }
    input /= (int) Math.pow(10, size(input) - length - startingPoint); // shift from end by division
    input = input % (int) Math.pow(10, length); // shift from start by division remainder
    if (input < 0 && startingPoint > 0) {
        input = Math.abs(input); // update sign for negative input
    }
    return input;
}

private static int size(int input) {
    int size = 1;
    while (input / 10 != 0) {
        size++;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return input < 0 ? ++size : size; // '-'sign is a part of size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a "number" is not what you want to do. You want to split the NUMERAL, which is the string representing a quantity (number). You can split the numeral just like any other literal (string): don't parse the user's input and use substring. If you want to make sure the literal is an actual numeral, parse it to see if an exception is thrown. If not, you have a numeral. But don't hold on to the integers, keep the strings instead.

Comment: At the very least the OP needs to understand the difference between these two concepts of the human-readable (typically decimal) character representation of a number vs its conceptually baseless (though typically binary) internal representation.  The English language does not even have good terminology to distinguish between the two, though the distinction is critical for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

You give the method a number, start, and end indexes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(getPartOfInt(93934934, 3, 7));`

}

public static int getPartOfInt(int number, int start, int end){
    Integer i = new Integer(number);
    char[] chars = i.toString().toCharArray();
    String str = "";
    for(int j = start; j < end && j < chars.length; j++){
        str += chars[j];
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

OR:

```
public static int getPartOfInt(int number, int start, int end){
    String str = new Integer(number).toString();
    return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, Math.min(end, str.length())));
}
```

Comment: See the second one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also first convert the number to String, like so:

```
int num = 456789;
String strNum = String.valueOf(num);
String part1 = strNum.substring(0, strNum.length() / 2 - 1);
String part2 = strNum.substring(strNum.length() / 2);
```

Then, you could convert it back to int, like so:

```
int part1Num = Integer.parseInt(part1);
int part2Num = Integer.parseInt(part2);
```

Now you can do all the arithmetic you want with those two int's.

Answer (score 0):

@DeanLeitersdorf Here's the function ( @clcto s solution)

```
int subinteger(int input, int from, int size)
{
    while (input > pow(10, size + from) - 1)
        input /= 10;
    return input % (int)pow(10, size);
}
```

This is a  c++ solution but i hope that you can convert it to Java easily